# How to make a generic function C

Tags: c, generics, struct, insert, hashmap

I have to create an HashMap. I created two structs. A `node struct` and a `table struct`. Second struct will "contain" my nodes. My trouble is the `insert` function: I have to insert in my table (*t) couple (key,value). The problem is that key and value type must be generic. So , I would like to insert int, double, char, ecc.. How can I make my function into a *generic function*?

**insert.c**

```
struct node{
    int key;
    int val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
struct table{
    int size;
    struct node **list;
};

int hashCode(int key){
    if(key>0)
        return key-1;
    return key+1;
}

void insert(struct table *t,int key,int val){
    int pos = hashCode(key);
    struct node *list = t->list[pos];
    struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node *temp = list;
    while(temp){
        if(temp->key==key){
            printf("%s", "Key already created");
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    newNode->next = list;
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->val = val;
    if(list!=NULL){
        list->prev = newNode; 
    }
    t->list[pos] = newNode;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
}
```

**main.c**

```
int main(){
    struct table *t = /* I create the structure */ ;
    insert(t,2,3);
    insert(t,3,4);
    insert(t,2,3);
    // insert(t,'a','c');  function insert should execute also with char, int, float, double ecc...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can use a `union` to store keys and values, and `enum` to suggest what data is stored.

Comment: I have never used union and enum, how can I use them in my function? @jha-G

Comment: You can create a generic hash implementation that is given a compare function for the key and it stores the key as a void data type (or pointer to void).

Comment: Insert parameters are Int, so how can I pass a char for example? I need to pass it all the type , not int only. @PaulOgilvie

Comment: you could also use `void *`  for `key` and `value` and add an extra parameter _type_ (could use enum ) in your `node` to decode to correct type when required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define the union like this :

```
union value {
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
//and so on
};
```

And your node like this :

```
struct node{
    int key;
    union value val;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};
```

You change your function argument like this :

```
void insert(struct table *t, int key, union value val) {}
```

And your main becomes (I use a macro to simplify the creation of unions) :

```
#define UVAL(v, k) (union value){ .k = v}

int main(){
    struct table * t = NULL; //Todo

    insert(t, 2, UVAL(3, i) );
    insert(t, 3, UVAL(4, i));
    insert(t, 2, UVAL(3, i));
    return 0;
}
```

With some floats instead :

```
int main(){
    struct table * t = NULL; //Todo

    insert(t, 2, UVAL(3.5f, f));
    insert(t, 3, UVAL(4.f,  f));
    insert(t, 2, UVAL(3.5f, f));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you what does `{.k = v}` mean in the define?

Comment: k represents the name of the field in the union. Here I pass i or f so, after macro expansion, it will become `.i` or `.f`

Answer (score -1):

Since C11 you can use `_Generic`

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define hashCode(x) _Generic((x), \
    int: hash_int, \
    double: hash_double \
)(x)

int hash_int(int value)
{
    printf("Hashing %d\n", value);
    return 42;
}

int hash_double(double value)
{
    printf("Hashing %f\n", value);
    return 42;
}

int main(void)
{
    hashCode(3);
    hashCode(3.14);
    return (0);
}
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic)

**Explanation**

> Provides a way to choose one of several expressions at compile time,
> based on a type of a controlling expression
>
> First, the type of controlling-expression undergoes lvalue
> conversions. The conversion is performed in type domain only: it
> discards the top-level cvr-qualifiers and atomicity and applies
> array-to-pointer/function-to-pointer transformations to the type of
> the controlling expression, without initiating any side-effects or
> calculating any values.
>
> The type after conversion is compared with type-names from the list of
> associations.
>
> If the type is compatible with the type-name of one of the
> associations, then the type, value, and value category of the generic
> selection are the type, value, and value category of the expression
> that appears after the colon for that type-name.
>
> If none of the type-names are compatible with the type of the
> controlling-expression, and the default association is provided, then
> the type, value, and value category of the generic selection are the
> type, value, and value category of the expression after the default :
> label.